# Malware scanner for Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is scanning VIRUS needed on Linux Distros?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/is-scanning-virus-needed-on-linux-distros)

What's a good malware scanner for Ubuntu?

**--update**

I just suspect something strange on my system, so I wondered if is there a malware scanner.

Comment: malware!! in linux?

Comment: You dont need any malware/virus scanner for ubuntu.

Comment: rootkits exist and are malware.  check the duplicate for details on virus scanners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there aren't many malwares on Linux in general as most programs you'll ever download and install are open-source and, if there is, the program will most likely have a very short lifespan; so there is no need for a malware scanner.

Comment: In an isolated system, potentially true. But what if he's connected to a network? The responsible thing (certainly in a corporate environment) to do is to ensure that you're not a carrier of malware (files passing through the system), even if not affected by it.

Comment: in all honesty, from experience I can say, most of the risk to windows systems would come from a malicious person, not a malicious program. I was in networked environments for a long time (years) without infecting a single windows computer, yet I was able to go around collecting windows viruses (Even tried to run them on wine, but they failed to work because of missing features) - I never was able to pass them on to anyone by just sitting on the network, and I was able to show people the lack of risk from running linux. no need for antimalware except on a server.