# Does Ubuntu really need an anti-virus?

Tags: viruses, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have antivirus software installed on a Linux distro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed-on-a-linux-distro)

Do i need install it anti-virus on ubuntu? or unnecessary? I just want to know this. please thanks.

please professional honest an opinions, thanks.