# Can malware enter Ubuntu?

Tags: security, malware

I have a desktop computer with Window 7 system and Ubuntu (installed by my boyfriend). Last week when I shopped online on Win7, I accidentally caught Eye Perform ads in Firefox. I Google and found [this post](https://www.removeitvirus.com/how-to-get-rid-ofremove-ads-by-eye-perform-from-ie-firefox-chrome/) which provides help in Windows and Mac OS system. The question is when I log into the Ubuntu system, it seems it's a bit slower than before. Had the malware entered the system? I dare not tell my BF yet. Please... any advice! Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't viruses an issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37198/why-arent-viruses-an-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking malware can affect Ubuntu.

But in dual boot system there is no way that this kind of malware gets from Windows to Ubuntu.

These systems do not share executable files. And Windows malware can not affect linux systems, if not used in wine.

But you can directly get a malicious add-on to Firefox in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, you really relax me not a bit.