# Can Ubuntu computers have network viruses

Tags: windows, malware

I know Ubuntu doesn't have viruses but if you do download something that has a virus that could infect windows, could it spread through the network and infect a windows PC on the same wireless network like a worm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't viruses an issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37198/why-arent-viruses-an-issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu doesn't have viruses

You mean malware and [yes it does have viruses.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Threats)

> could it spread through the network and infect a windows PC on the same wireless network like a worm?

Not unless it either runs on Linux to go through the network or it gets transferred through other means.

Answer (score 0):

at the university where I am working we have mainly Ubuntu systems and a few windows computers also.  Through the last few years we never had experience any problems like that, beside from the Windows Computers, which once or twice got a virus.

So I dont think that you need to worry about it!

Just my thoughts