# Why aren't there viruses in all Linux based systems?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, security, viruses, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have antivirus software installed on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed-on-ubuntu)

I only need an ***article*** which explain why We don't have **viruses** in all Linux based systems? and also explain if we can ***make*** some in the future of these most **secure** systems?

Comment: Maybe it's also off-topic coz the OP is asking if we can make some viruses for Linux in the future :P

Answer (score 1):

This article [here](http://librenix.com/?inode=21) explains the Linux Virus scenario pretty well. For more detailed discussion see the Q&A pointed out by Jorge in comments.