# Did I Somehow Get Infected with Spyware or Virus?

Tags: command-line, security, viruses

So I Was trying to Install Ubuntu restricted Extras, and well this poped up in the terminal.

```
  www.actingcareersnow.comCasting Calls For Kids & Teens. Audition Now! Ages 9 to 29. 
[1] 3241 
Teens.: command not found 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ Talent Search Open Call 
www.actingcareersnow.comCasting: command not found 
Talent: command not found 
[1]+ Exit 127 www.actingcareersnow.comCasting Calls For Kids 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ www.talentshowcase.tvChild-Adult. Meet Top Industry Pros Looking to Interview New Talent ! 
www.talentshowcase.tvChild-Adult.: command not found 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ Casting 
Casting Calls 
www.actingcareersnow.comCasting Calls For Kids & Teens. Audition Now! Ages 9 to 29. 
Talent Search Open Call 
www.talentshowcase.tvChild-Adult. Meet Top Industry Pros Looking to Interview New Talent ! 
Casting 
www.starnow.com/CastingActors, Models, Musicians, Dancers Find Work, Get Discovered Today! 
Extras Wanted - Get jobs 
www.exploretalent.com/ExtrasAudition Open Calls for Paid Jobs! Movies, TV, Theater, CommercialsCasting: command not found 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ www.starnow.com/CastingActors, Models, Musicians, Dancers Find Work, Get Discovered Today! 
bash: www.starnow.com/CastingActors,: No such file or directory 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ Extras Wanted - Get jobs 
Extras: command not found 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ www.exploretalent.com/ExtrasAudition Open Calls for Paid Jobs! Movies, TV, Theater, CommercialsuCasting Calls 
bash: www.exploretalent.com/ExtrasAudition: No such file or directory 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ www.actingcareersnow.comCasting Calls For Kids & Teens. Audition Now! Ages 9 to 29. 
[1] 3255 
Teens.: command not found 
gagandeep@Fullmetal:~$ Talent Search Open Call 
www.actingcareersnow.comCasting: command not found 
Talent: command not found 
[1]+ Exit 127 www.actingcareersnow.comCasting Calls For Kids 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ www.talentshowcase.tvChild-Adult. Meet Top Industry Pros Looking to Interview New Talent ! 
www.talentshowcase.tvChild-Adult.: command not found 
kevin@Fullmetal:~$ Casting 
Casting: command not found
```

Does this mean I am infected? That message came up in the terminal.

Comment: if you reboot and try again, do you get the same issue?

Comment: Nope I rebooted, and everything installed perfectly, haven't seen that message since. should I be worried?

Comment: It looks like you had the spam-looking text in the clipboard and inadvertently pasted in into the terminal.

Comment: Um could you explain what you mean by "spam-looking text in the clipboard?" Whats a clipboard? And Should I delete Ubuntu, and re-install it?

Comment: Clipboard is a place where you store data if you copy them by (for example) selecting some text and then pressing Ctrl+c. You might have selected this text at a "sponsored links" section here: http://yellowpages.aol.com/talent-agencies-and-casting-services/nj/haddonfield/

Comment: Thank You! That actually makes a lot of sense, because that seems highly plausible, and I do remember trying to copy and paste something from a webpage. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Selecting the text in the browser and then accidentally clicking the middle button (likely the scroll wheel) on the mouse is enough. Has happened to me numerous times. No reason to worry about infections. Just try to be a bit more careful with the mouse.

Comment: @arrange - post your comment as an answer to close this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you had the spam-looking text in the clipboard and inadvertently pasted in into the terminal. You might have selected this text at a "sponsored links" section  [here](http://yellowpages.aol.com/talent-agencies-and-casting-services/nj/haddonfield/)... :)

Comment: Yea! I've seen that page before! Thank You so much! This puts my mind at ease.

Answer (score 1):

Normally linux doesnt suffer from windows based spyware and viruses.  If you feel unsure, see this [AUQuestion for antivirus advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed-on-ubuntu) and potential anti-virus products you can use to download and scan your system.

There is an excellent section on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=338) which you should consult if in doubt.  If there was a virus spreading - that forum will be quickly updated by affected users.  There are several "Stickies" as well will also help you to diagnose security issues such as this.

Answer (score 1):

It it's also possible for javascript to copy things to your clipboard.

If a malicious script runs this could happen but it seems unlikely that this is a serious issue. If you continue to get it from one particular website report it (it could be a dodgy advert).