# Will I be prone to viruses?

Tags: security, viruses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed-on-ubuntu)

I replaced windows because of the viruses and such. I was wondering if I had to worry much about them with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't worry much about viruses in Linux. However, you should still be careful at scam websites that steal info and such.

If you really need want to be extra safe just install an antivirus software. 
Clam AV Virus Scaner is found in Ubuntu Software Center.

For more lecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware

Viruses are also kept off because of Ubuntu using a central software repository, so that software is checked for being virus-free. This is a good safety feature unless you use software repositories by other people. You should always check if they are trustworthy.

Security bugs also get fixed very fast, because of a lot of people able to fix and actually fixing these, due to Open Source Software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worry about Microsoft Based Systems Viruses, you can feel tranquil. Even when you can run a windows based program including a virus, etc. It will probably won't find a way to do what it would do with ease in a Windows Based System. Anyway, take in consideration the recommendations provided by @tibike on his answer in order to make sure you are apart of any malware.