# Antivirus softwares for ubuntu

Tags: viruses, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Yesterday in a certain web site I found that there are so many antivirus programs available for ubuntu.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/free-linux-antivirus-programs/

My question is .... Is it necessary to install an antivirus software in ubuntu because I have heard that ubuntu it self is highly protected against threats and Linux OSs don't subject to viruses at all.