# Does Linux Need Antivirus

Tags: antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Just a thought came in my mind that whether linux need AV. If not really then **what are the reasons** that Windows need AV and linux don't need any.

Thanks