# Installing McAfee antivirus on Ubuntu

Tags: antivirus

I want to install McAfee antivirus On Ubuntu. I've downloaded McAfee for Linux.
But I don't know how to:

Copy pam_unix.so from `/lib/security` of a 32-bit Ubuntu (till version 10.10) system
to a temporary directory `/tmp` on the 64-bit Ubuntu system. From Ubuntu 11.04
onwards, pam_unix.so is available under `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` folder.

Do I need to download the whole 32-bit version to get this pam_unix.so file?

Comment: You may be interested in this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: Do you follow specific instructions? What version of McAffee do you use? It would be nice if you put more information into your question.

Comment: Are you using a server or maintaining some kind of mailing system with Windows partitions or Windows users? (Only reasons to use antivirus)

Answer (score 1):

Without meaning to sound flippant, it's unlikely you'll need antivirus. Unless you're in a really high-sensitivity environment it's unlikely you'll come across a situation where you'll face a Linux virus. In any case I would recommend ClamAV as an open source antivirus product. You can install it through `apt-get install clamav`.

The majority of antivirus products I've come across - particularly Sophos antivirus - only scan for Windows viruses, and even then only do that by hashing the file. This means if a virus changes even one byte in the file which contains it, the AV product wouldn't think it's a virus any more.

Comment: I was trying to be pro active. I will try the clam.

Comment: It's ok, firewalls and AV are the first things people assume they need when they try out Linux. Since most linux desktop distros don't start with any services listening to the network it isn't necessary to have a firewall, and equally the use of Executable Bits in most filesystems mean that (except for a few circumstances) programs need to be explicitly set as runnable, so viruses can't sneak their way onto the system. As a whole, Windows' poor design and security mechanisms is the reason lots of AV products exist.