# Does Ubuntu need Anti-malware?

Tags: antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have ‘antivirus software’ installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

I'm new to Ubuntu (12.10), does it need anti-malware and what is the best anti-malware for Ubuntu?

I'm asking, because unlike Windows, Linux is not as often the target of hackers since Linux users are more tech savvy, 99% of the time.

Linux are not attacked as frequent I believe since it does not have a huge user community like windows has.

Comment: It's not duplicate, because the questions differ from eachother. He asks "do i need", the other asks "how does viruses work in linux, and do i need anti-malware?" something that way.

Comment: @denNorske: Looks like a duplicate to me. The other question asks everything this one does.

Answer (score 1):

There are not so many people in the world (compared to windows and mac) that are using ubuntu, so there are nearly no malware found for ubuntu. So, no, you dont need it unless you install 100'eds of other applications you dont know what are for and where they come from.

So, again, i never used it, and i never will unless it becomes a problem :P

Answer (score 1):

There are rumours that increasing number of malware will come up to open source
software (included Linux). - it looks that in recent time there have been more
attempts to log into Linux system ( into mine ... - but I really have nothing "interesting" on my system).

Well, if you run wine for windows-applications you should have clamav installed
and rkhunter too resp. chkrootkit. windows-malware cannot harm on a Unix-System but can be molesting like a fly in your soup.