# Does Kaspersky Antivirus 2012 work on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, antivirus

I'm new to linux and I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop , I just wanted to know if it is possible to install kaspersky on Ubuntu.

I know that we can install .exe files in ubuntu with wine. Can I use wine to install kaspersky antivirus 2012?

Comment: be sure to read the related questions in the right-hand column, including http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: I'm thinking of running Ubuntu in my machine as a second OS by using a hard disk that I'll just swap out using a bay, so there would be no cross talk between data platforms. I don't run any HDs inside the box they are all externally swappable. I used to share disks and files with a guy who ran linux on his machines and I often had to deal with viruses and trojans that were all over his files. Probably he had them because they were in the files he downloaded from the web. He downloaded all sorts of stuff. Ubuntu wouldn't be the only OS in my life so while it's true that the current crop of viru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this list of Anti-Virus application for Linux OS, Kaspersky is available for Linux:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications

And I recommend you to read this ubuntu help page about antivirus on linux:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus .

Here is a direct link to kaspersky's current .deb file: 
http://products.kaspersky-labs.com/products/english/antispam/deb/kas-3-3.0.284-1.i386.deb

You can install this .DEB file with the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i kas-3-3.0.284-1.i386.deb
```

Comment: Hmmm okays, Kaspersky endpoint security is available for linux only but i`ve an original kaspersky 2012 internet security antivirus so that's why i have posted my query here :)

Comment: Then you can access it through wine or you can request them to extend you key to Linux version also . I hope they can do that .

Comment: Ohh okays, thanks for the reply. I really appreciate about that:)

Answer (score 9):

It is common for new Linux users to wonder what the best antivirus for Linux is after coming from Windows. Antivirus applications are unnecessary for Ubuntu or Linux in general. There are only a handful of viruses on Linux, and most of them are "proof of concept" type viruses, so you would have to hunt them down, download them and manually install them yourself. There are very few, if any viruses in the wild. I do not personally know anyone who runs Ubuntu/Linux and uses an antivirus program, and know no one who has ever had an issue. At most, people run antivirus checks on shared files, to make sure that they do not pass any viruses on to Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

You can install with wine but it is useless. It will only scan and protect from viruses only designed for windows. And windows viruses doesn't work with linux. And ubuntu doesn't need a third party anti virus software - It has a built-in one.
Welcome

Comment: hmmm okays thanks for your reply. So it`s a chump idea to install it on my laptop and it will be better to install an anti-virus which supports for linux os?

Comment: no point in installing kaspersky for windows in ubuntu with wine. And go to http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/why-use-ubuntu , you can see that it has no viruses if you scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Windows version of any Antivirus program will work on linux and protect it, but you can try other antivirus programs, Avast has a Linux version and is completely free (as in free of paying) only requires registration in their official page and an email account where you will receive your license key.

http://www.avast.com/es-mx/download-software#tab3