# How to make Ubuntu let me manage the Virus Security?

Tags: 12.04, icons, security, system-tray, antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to have ‘antivirus software’ installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Ubuntu 12.04. (Sorry if this is a duplicate)

On my previous version of Windows (I've deleted that) I was able to manage my security, like Scan, delete viruses and many more. Can I have access to the Virus security in Ubuntu or at least have an icon in the tray to see what it's doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed an antivirus program in Ubuntu? It does not come with one. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: Yes, but if you look at Ubuntu (At the website) is says it has protection. And if I can have an antivirus, what would you recommend?

Comment: You might want to see this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/10373/44179

Comment: Ok. I've seen that one, but what antivirus should I use?