# What automated intrusion notification/detection setup is good for home desktop use?

Tags: software-recommendation, security, firewall, logs

I've been using Linux for quite a while now and I always feel the need to have a passive software / script setup which can alert me of any suspicious network activities like scans, failed login attempts, etc. on the fly via email or by visual/audio notifications.

I know how to look up through logs and stuff but for the most part it is a manual, time consuming process. I'm looking for something that is semi/fully automated with some good log parsing capabilities.

I'm aware of IDS systems for monitoring networks like Snort, etc. but they are an overkill for the average home user and a painful process to get up and running.

What is a good option for me as a home user?

Comment: How do you define 'passive'? As in, something you run once in a while yourself to see if something fishy was going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple and effective general solution is to use ***logcheck***.

```
sudo apt-get install logcheck
[edit /etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf to your liking]
```

***logcheck*** periodically scans all the logs efficiently (starting where it left off last time), filters what it sees to eliminate anything considered normal, and optionally emails alerts with anything that doesn't match the normal/routine patterns.

The main idea is to watch-out for appearance of any serious entries in your log files, all of them, all the time, so ***you*** don't have to.

***logcheck*** is highly configurable (`man logcheck`).  You may configure everything, including:

- frequency of checks
- which log files are checked
- what is considered normal vs not
- where to email the alerts (abnormal events) to

and more. Your ignore (normal/routine) patterns reside in multiple files under **/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.*** and you may customize them to your needs; mainly you may want to add your own patterns to ignore.  The default Ubuntu package comes with an extensive set of files with ignore patterns for many services already, so there's not much to add unless your system is unusual in what it runs. There are 3 sets of pre-configured ignore file profiles:  *ignore.d.workstation*, *ignore.d.server*, and *ignore.d.paranoid* which you can pick from.

The main idea behind ***logcheck*** is that the various services running on a system, already log abnormal events. E.g. *sshd* or *pam* already log authentication failures.  So the main missing components are:

- *filtering what's normal*
- The *alerting* service

Both of which are provided by ***logcheck*** in a convenient package.  You may combine ***logcheck*** with any other logging. For example *iptables* can be configured to *syslog* any network connection attempts that are not explicitly allowed by adding the rules:

```
 iptables -A input -j LOG
 iptables -A input -j DROP
```

immediately after all the allow rules.

I find ***logcheck*** to be much more helpful than ***logwatch*** (suggested in other answers) because it comes pre-packaged with a very large number of rules to ignore what's considered normal activity. The result is a much higher signal/noise ratio in the alerts it emails. YMMV.

Another advantage of ***logcheck*** is that it is *orthogonal* to any service that logs, so there's no duplication of function. Whenever you add a new service which uses `syslog` to log events, abnormal or not, into any file under `/var/log` you start getting alerts for it automatically.

***HOWTO:***

> Since `logcheck` already comes preconfigured, two lines at the top of
>   this answer essentially cover all you need to get started.  Just
>   install it, and go over the top configuration file:
>   `/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf` to change your email address
>   so `logcheck` emails alerts to you.
>
> Here's a [friendly reference going over the second step in more
>   detail](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/logcheck.htm).
>   Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, these instructions should work on Ubuntu too.
>   [Here is another good reference](http://bluelightav.org/display/BLUE/How+to+administer+logcheck).
>
> Once you install, the continuous improvement process starts.
>   Over time, you refine your rules to ignore anything that you already know about
>   and feel shouldn't be of concern.
>   This refinement process is as simple as adding text lines to a file
>   in your favorite text editor.
>
> Each line in an ignore file is an extended regular expression (see `man 7 regex`), but you may use simple strings as long as they match the log line you want to ignore. Just remember that characters like `*`, `?`, '+', `[]`, `()` are special in a regular expression, so if they actually appear in the log lines, you would have to escape them with a backslash `\` in the ignore files.
>
> In other words: if you get an alert you don't want to get,
>   look at the log line that was emailed to you, and add a pattern
>   that matches it, as one line to any ignore file of your choice.  I suggest using
>   `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.<yourloglevel>/my-ignores` as your personal ignore
>   file. Where `<yourloglevel>` is one of `paranoid`, `server`, or
>   `workstation` (as you've already selected in
>   the main config file: `/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf`).  Look at the examples in other
>   ignore files to see how to account for text that changes all the time like process-IDs, or time-stamps. There are lots of existing examples to learn from.

One last tip: `logcheck` comes with a little useful utility called `logcheck-test` which is very handy for testing new rules. `man logcheck-test` for details.

Comment: Hi, I like the idea behind logcheck...can you please point me to an in depth guide for that? Thanks :)

Comment: @irenicus09: Just added howto section with an optional link for reference.

Comment: Congratz on winning the bounty, very well written answer man. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a lot of systems on your network, setting up an IDS like Snort is probably overkill (especially if you don't have any network services on your machine). I suggest starting by configuring logwatch to send yourself a report of what's going on on your system. Once you have that up, configure your syslog so that you get as much relevant information as possible.

Comment: Hello, I like your answer...but could you please share a bit more details on how to do that. Messing up with configurations can be quite tricky, especially for an inexperienced user. But I'd appreciate if you could point me towards an in depth guide for that. Thanks.

Comment: @irenicus09 I think this should be sufficient: [How to setup Logwatch on Ubuntu-based systems](http://cilab.math.upatras.gr/mikeagn/content/how-setup-logwatch-ubuntu-based-systems)

Comment: thanks for the guide, I've successfully setup logwatch & I like it. For port scan monitor I've also setup portsentry and I'll be trying other tools and stuff before I finalise which one's the best for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Intrusion detection is needed for sure when you run services (ftp, web, nfs, ssh etc) in your network. This is because they are exposed on the internet and due to :

- miss-configuration
- software vulnerabilities

they need daily monitoring by an experienced network administrator. If you run this services, you probably have already the minimum knowledge how to avoid this problems.

If you don't run any of this services, then your internet router firewall, has already blocked any incoming connection on ports. To scan your networks router

- just visit https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2
- click "proceed"
- select "All ports" to check for any open ports

If you are all green, then you are all good.

Last but not least, probably your router has built-in Intrusion detection system (because 99% of all routers run a striped down linux server). For this, you must check the manual of your routers manufacturer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It is quite insightful and I'm aware of everything that you're talking about. But my point is let's say I'm running various services on my system, how exactly do I track activities from a security perspective. I need a simple, easy to use solution as a home user and I think you avoided that part :)