# Way of receiving alerts on login attempts, whether successful or not?

Tags: server, bash, ssh, login, notification

I believe my linux machine to be reasonably protected from external login. But since I am mildy paranoid, I would like to be alerted when there is a login attempt made to the server, whether successful or not.

Scanning the site, I cannot find any unison way of doing this. As far as I can tell, for unsuccessful attempts [logcheck has been recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280944/what-automated-intrusion-notification-detection-setup-is-good-for-home-desktop-u), and for successful ones [the sshrc or (perhaps even more) pam_exec method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful). I like two-stones-in-one-throw methods, and wonder whether any of you pros know if there is a way of getting one of these methods to do both? PAM in particular seems to be a smart place to do things, since it is after all, from what I can tell, the central authentication system on my ubuntu machine.

Any advice?

Comment: An interesting post would be http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html?m=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use `cron` with a silly little script to check `/var/log/auth.log` every 10 minutes. If you set it up correctly, `cron` will email output wherever you like so we just need a script to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /var/log/auth.log | perl -MDate::Parse -ne '
  print if /login|ssh/ && /^(\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s/ && str2time($1) > time-600'
```

This is based around [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665179/12870) by [F. Hauri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765658/f-hauri).

That's just looking for items with `login` or `ssh` in. You might want to add more or just exclude some. But on my system here's what it generates:

```
Aug 29 10:19:50 bert sudo:      oli : TTY=pts/10 ; PWD=/home/oli ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/login
Aug 29 10:19:52 bert login[15544]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user oli by oli(uid=0)
Aug 29 10:19:54 bert login[15544]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user oli
Aug 29 10:20:11 bert sshd[15614]: Accepted publickey for oli from ::1 port 41663 ssh2: RSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Aug 29 10:20:11 bert sshd[15614]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user oli by (uid=0)
```

Save that script as something like `/usr/local/sbin/checkauth` (and `chmod u+x` it) and then you can add a root crontab line with `sudo crontab -e`:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/sbin/checkauth
```

Stick a `MAILTO="email@example.com"` line at the top of the cron file too and (provided there's a mailserver installed — install `postfix` if not) you'll get emails of the output, *iff* there is any output.