# How to setup minimalistic log file monitoring for one computer?

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

I am wondering if there is a simple monitoring solution to watch over the host machines log files and notify me in some way (I use the terminal frequently, so MOTD/byobu or something else like "you have mail on this host" would be sufficient). The background is that I had a few USB related issues in the past day, example:

```
Apr 12 07:49:12 za20 kernel: [76757.651125] hub 4-2:1.0: port 3 nyet suspended
Apr 12 07:49:13 za20 kernel: [76758.746970] hub 4-2:1.0: port 3 nyet suspended
Apr 12 07:49:14 za20 kernel: [76759.841948] hub 4-2:1.0: port 3 nyet suspended
Apr 12 07:49:15 za20 kernel: [76760.936854] hub 4-2:1.0: port 3 nyet suspended
```

It would have been nice to know about that while I was at home, but I noticed this only when I accessed my computer through SSH looking at kernel.log knowing that there have been issues in the past days. What I didn't expect was that this was already going on while I was at home. So, yes a tool that looks for unusual log file activity like the same message appearing in a log file very frequently would be nice to have.

What do you recommend? Ideally the setup should be simple enough so that users who don't have much experience with monitoring and data analysis can set this up.

Comment: There is a [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange where this may be more suitable.  Most software recommendation will otherwise be highly opinion based or insanely broad for the scope of this site.

Comment: A simple solution could be to create a cron job to search for the patterns after certain times..if found will send you a mail or do whatever you want..

Comment: Looks like [logcheck](http://askubuntu.com/a/283332/40581) does what I had in mind. (For getting the mails see: http://askubuntu.com/q/2261/40581)