# Linux vs Windows 7

Tags: uninstall

I've inherited a nice small laptop with Linux on it. I am used to Windows Word, Live Mail etc. Shall I uninstall Linux and install Windows?

If I stay with the Linux, what should I use for security, as I won't have Microsoft Security Essentials? Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: This is a good question for http://ubuntu-discourse.org/

Comment: This is still a duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/q/10373/169736 if it gets reopen.

Answer (score 3):

First, Microsoft developed Microsoft Security Essentials because their 
software/operating systems are full of bugs and easily exploitable!!
So they need Microsoft Security Essentials just to keep your computer
(and their software) relatively safe on a day to day basis.
Linux software is very different in many ways so the possibilities of
viruses, trojans and other exploits are very small.

I would suggest downloading Ubuntu and trying it on your laptop
for a couple of weeks to see if you like it. I think you will.
If you need/prefer a desktop that looks like windows try installing cinnamon 
desktop on your Ubuntu or perhaps try another Linux distro that has
Cinnamon or Mate as one of its default installs. (Try Linux Mint or PCLinuxOS)

As for Microsoft Word, I think that you will find Libreoffice to be
an excellent and nearly identical substitute for it. You can even open
and edit Word documents with Libreoffice.
Thunderbird is a great email program that you might like a lot. It is
made by the same people that make Firefox. 
A good place to see a list of the other Linux distros is distrowatch.com
But I really like Ubuntu because I found it to be extremely stable and
its support is fantastic.
Personally I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the Cinnamon desktop on 2 computers
and 3 laptops because I just really like it.

Here is a link to a helpful thread about the different desktop environments
you can use
[What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Analogy: Because Ubuntu uses e.g. AppArmor (Security Essentials is obsolete in Windows 8 due to Windows Defender and other refined mechanisms), Ubuntu must be full of bugs (proof found on Launchpad :p) and easily exploitable. Uhm, no. This claim immediately backfires.

Comment: I have all my files on Word. If I send documents made in Libreoffice, will receptors be able to open them. And how about PDF. Can I save a document as a PDF file?

Comment: There us actually painfully little difference in attack vector between Windows and other operating systems for trojans, viruses and exploits. Well viruses and exploits are a little too complicated to generalise like that but trojans are just little userspace applications. If anything, Ubuntu's awesome scripting environment makes it much easier to deploy nasties like that. The complacency in falling back on Linux's superior design is far more dangerous than anything in Windows these days.