# Can we run same program or antivirus software at windows as well as on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, antivirus

I would like to access some windows programs on Ubuntu.
If at all possible I would like to access programs installed on windows like antivirus software, flash, silverlight etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: [Flash install](http://www.itworld.com/software/304991/install-adobe-flash-player-ubuntu-1210) - [Silverlight Install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1879015) - The advantage of Linux over Windows is that there are a lot less viruses - [see here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1228214/is-ubuntu-safer-than-windows-against-hacking-viruses) - so you may not need anti-virus software - But you can use [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page)

Comment: It's neither recommended nor useful to run anti-virus software made for Windows on a non-Windows system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Comment: Ubuntu does not need an antivirus, even if you're running Windows programs. No program can ever damage your computer without your permission, so as long as you're careful you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

## The answer is  actually yes  with some quid proquos  etc ifs but and maybe's and so on.

I am not going to give you the win  advice as that has already been covered.

### Yes but just not the exe versions..

So clamwin has a very good linux  version

to update you use  cli and  freshclam

go to  clam web site full instructions  are there,  if you are dual booting then install clamwin on your windows partition and clamav through your  ubuntu repo's

comodo does a paid  version too

Answer (score 1):

You can run a lot of windows programs on Ubuntu but you'll need wine.

You cannot however run programs from your windows partition using wine. This is done on purpose because a lot of people messed up there windows installs trying to run it using (past versions of) wine.

You can check if your program works using wine by checking it [here](http://www.winehq.org/). (use the top right search bar to find your desired program)

For the examples you gave us there are Linux alternatives. For flash run this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I personally don't use antivirus software on my linux installation because I only give my sudo password to trusted software and I know what I'm doing but if you want to use antivirus in linux you can use [avast](http://www.avast.com/index), [bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/business/antivirus-for-unices.html), clamav or [avg](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download.prd-alf)

Silverlight has a linux alternative called [moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

"NO" its not possible , but for some software’s like adobe photo-shop and all, you can use wine and wine tricks for installing windows based software’s but you cant use them on ubuntu by installing them in windows.

Comment: A) Photoshop DOES work - http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=17 B) You can always use [GIMP instead](http://www.gimp.org/)

Comment: I know I have currently working Adobe photoshop cs6 on ma ubuntu, i was saying that you cant use softwares installed in windows on ubuntu and if you want to then you have to use wine and wine tricks as i did. and "yes" you cant use all windows based softwares on ubuntu through wine.

Comment: Yeah, but the questioneer is asking if you can run programs installed on his windows partition which isn't possible since wine blocked this. so Sushantp606 is correct

Comment: Whoops... Nice with the `the questioneer` -  the `the enquirer perhaps`?

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden exactly thats wat i was saying. thanks

Comment: Yeah, enquirer is a better word but questioneer seems much more adventurous. I actually only use it for people who just asked there first question.

Answer (score 0):

In generally: No. 
Windows and Ubuntu (Linux) are different platforms and software is developed/compiled for a specific platform. That means you can't run windows software at ubuntu and vice versa.

Have a look at [SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows).

Anyway, there are possibilites to run windows software at ubuntu, for example using [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine). But I wouldn't recommend this if it isn't really necessary. It's better to search for a ubuntu equivalent to the windows software you would like to have in ubuntu and some windows software is simple not needed with ubuntu, e.g. antivirus software.

Answer (score 0):

You can run some windows programs in wine, which can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. A list of which programs work in wine, and which programs don't can be found here:

http://appdb.winehq.org/

As far as antivirus goes, there are some antivirus products available for Ubuntu, but they typically only scan for Windows viruses rather than linux ones. I would recommend Comodo Antivirus For Linux, though it's one of the more difficult to install, alternatively you can install ClamAV from the Ubuntu Software Center.

How To Install Software Using The Ubuntu Software Center:

www.techhive.com/article/202571/how_to_install_apps_in_lucid_lynx_using_ubuntu_software_center.html

How To Install Comodo Antivirus For Linux 1.1 X86-64 On Ubuntu 12.10 - Desktop X86-64:

http://postbin.djun.net/pages/article11.php

Answer (score 0):

1st: There is almost no virus in Ubuntu provided you update;

2nd: For Windows programs you may use [PlayOnLunix](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.playonlinux.com/&ei=ON_HUvfQLZDrrAfItYGYDw&usg=AFQjCNHzU4tWA2S38FYD5owYjtKkEOUIDA&sig2=-Zx6M-2L8tIWleBp1UExhg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk);

Use F-Secure to configure your firewall.