# How to get Avast! Running on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, security, antivirus

I know in the current time, anti-virus isn’t exactly needed for Linux,however I still wish to install some form of protective layer. I had previously downloaded a .deb for the installation of Avast! for Linux, but the Ubuntu Software Centre gave me a warning saying the file was of bad origins. I’m at a dead end here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avast! is for Windows, not Ubuntu or any other Linux. Where did you get a .deb for it? If not for it, what was the .deb for? It's not clear what you're asking here. You can open Software Center and search for `clamav` and install that if you want an anti-virus app on Ubuntu.

Comment: The file I downloaded was labelled as avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb downloaded from http://files.avast.com/files/linux/avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb . When I opened the .deb through the software centre, a warning had popped up saying "This Package is of Bad Quality". As far as I was aware, Avast had made versions of the Anti Virus for linux in the past, unless my reading were incorrect. Sorry for any confusion"

Comment: @dobey there is a version of avast for Linux, but the deb file is "of bad quality" it doesn't provide the right info to uninstall if I remember correctly.

Comment: @TrailRider Yes, so it seems to exist. However, it also seems to be old and unsupported (I can find no reference to it on avast.com and the "download" buttons all give me the Windows installer).

Comment: @Jbuch14 Have you tried just clicking the `Ignore and Install Anyway` button when the _Bad Quality_ error pops up?

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, it does not uninstall correctly if you force it to install; you have to remove the files by hand.  It also seems that it did not work correctly....I would find another option.....

Comment: There is a decent scanner in the Ubuntu that you can install with the software Center.  It is clamAV-it is  used via terminal or you can install [clamtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clamtk/) which will give you a GUI and will install clamAV as well.

Comment: @dobey I have not, and I dont think I will bother trying to force install it, especially if Id need to remove the files by hand if anything went wrong. I should be alright without an Anti-Virus software, I was more or less curious to try it out. Thanks for all the help guys :)

Comment: @TrailRider Ill give ClamTK a look. I just prefer Graphical Interfaces over programs running in the terminal.

Comment: @dobey you can still find it around, I think you have to search the business section to find it on avast's website. However,as far as I know, you are correct, it is no longer supported; I think it still gets database updates, but it has not been updated to work with newer versions of Ubuntu....

Comment: used that a long time ago.. gave lots of false positives! I can't recall much but that I had to click.. click.. click.. click... ... ...

Comment: however, these links might interest you **[Linux Virus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Linuxvirus)**, **[Antivirus in Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)**, **[Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported any longer by Avast. As the package itself is broken, your only options are to force the install, use a different scanner such as `clamav`, not use a virus scanner at all, or [contact Avast support](http://www.avast.com/support) to complain about the issue.