# Is any antivirus required in Ubuntu to use credit cards online -- suggestion needed

Tags: antivirus

Hope you are doing well.
I know this topic has been answered in details in one thread - [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

But I am still little confused, the only thing that I use Windows 7 for now is for paying bills with credit cards.

My credit card was once hacked, so I guess I am a little paranoid.

I would really appreciate, if someone tell me if I need to install anti viruse in Ubuntu, and if yes, what I should go for?

Any help will be earnestly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reasons FOR antivirus on Ubuntu:

> - You are running a file or mail server with Windows clients.
> - You wish to scan files before transferring them, by email, flash drive, etc., to a Windows machine".

Here is the [great information about security](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=510812).