# Is There a Flawless Working Antivirus program for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, antivirus

I tried to install Clamav, Avira, Bitdefender and Comodo to install on my Ubuntu Unity 14.04 OS but couldn’t able to success. All have a problem to resolve. Is there a flawless program that workouts? Can anybody help in this regard?

Thank you,

Regards,

Simko

Comment: Personally I recommend DrWeb, but seriously, it is pointless unless you have Samba server.

Comment: Again, Do you know an antivirus program that runs flawless on Ubuntu 14.04? I can not find an antivirus program for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need an anti-virus program.  Your Ubuntu should not be susceptible to viruses.

Comment: Actually I need. Recently one of my friend that uses Windows told me that I always send him emails with viruses. So, this is not a good point I think.

Comment: Hmmm... Ive never heard of something like this happening.  I honestly however do not think that it would be your operating system.  Maybe something over the internet or something flawed in your email program.

Comment: @SimkoSukak if your friend uses Windows, I bet that *he* is the one that has the "viruses".

Comment: Very good point Lucio.  Like I said Ubuntu is not susceptible to viruses

Comment: Linux does not have viruses.  Ubuntu is one of the reason why Linux is better.

Comment: @Virusboy That is so not true. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: @Venki Majority of those Answers point to a Linux is secure not to require it.  Which is true, I have even been to ClamAV website and a million blogs stating that AVs are completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Virusboy right. Would be happy if you state about this *elaborately* in an answer(or upvote an existing answer that explains your view) [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/10287/do-we-need-a-big-list-question-on-anti-virus-softwares)