# Is a virus scanner really needed with wine?

Tags: wine, antivirus, clamav

I use wine for two things, playing World of warcraft and using spotify. Is a virus scanner needed for me? I tried to use clamAV but i download it from the software center and it says my version is outdated, i tried to upgrade it but i don't know how to do that. I also like to stick with the "no virus protection needed" that linux is known for, since I've been a windows user for many years.

Comment: If you use windows in wine you need antivirus for windows file that run in wine. That virus can not effect the ubuntu files, but your windows files may get effected.

Comment: That's true, i never thought of it that way.

Comment: See also: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Answer (score 1):

Well, a "Windows Virus" is not going to run without Wine, and if you see that wine is running while you are not really using it, you should see what program is actually using it. But it's very unlikely that you will get a virus that way, I can't say it's imposible, but now you know how to detect one if it exists.

So I would not be worried about wine and viruses, because if you get one, it will be through your internet browser or mail for sure.