# Windows Softwares in 14.04?

Tags: software-installation

does 14.04 support all the softwares which work in window 8.1 like photoshop , corel draw, and all games like nfs, xmen, pes ?
I don't need any antivirus for this 0S , right ?

Pls reply

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. The answers here are provided by volunteers who invest their spare time to help others. Please make sure that you at least read _some_ documentation / sources before asking.

Comment: You should avoid using Windows software if possible, there are Ubuntu alternatives for most common software.  If you need to use some however, the question this is being closed for explains how you can get some Windows software to work.  For your second question see: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/q/10373/107450)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Windows software using [PlayOnLinux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux/). You can check compatibility [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/).
And you don't need any antivirus. Just make sure you install all system updates.

Comment: PlayOnLinux is not listed for 14.04. And there are enough people who break their Linux' security by following bad advice. So it's _not_ enough to "install all system updates".

Comment: @ClassStacker Current version of Ubuntu isn't listed. The list should be used only when installing on older versions.