# Suggested Antivirus for Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: 14.04, server, antivirus

I have Ubuntu 14.04 server installed in my office. We're treating it as a local server. I have downloaded all our stuff from our dedicated hosting server (as server have viruses) to my local Ubuntu server.

So, as all the files are infected do i use any antivirus to clean all the files ??

Means how can i get rid of the viruses ?? If yes please suggest me some free antivirus for the same..

Thanks

Comment: @Rinzwind No we have purchased the hosting for our websites which are infected with viruses. But now i'm downloading those files to my local ubuntu server !! did you get me now ?

Comment: @Rinzwind No, i mean it is the hosting server (hosting from Go Daddy) i think now u will gt me !! isn't ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/11025/15811 :) It will scan for virusses but all of them will be for Windows virusses.

Comment: @Rinzwind ok will try :) thnx

Comment: If you use it in your office, you might probably have to pay for it, except you use an open-source/freeware scanner that also allows commercial use (ClamAV maybe, but that does no live scanning). Scanners that have this and work also on Ubuntu are e.g. Avast, but they are free for private use only.

Answer (score 3):

A widely-used package, especially in combination with mail services, is clamav.
It is fairly easy to install, and you will find tutorials quickly. 
As a quick start:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
sudo freshclam
clamscan -r <insert repository you want to scan here>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to contribution to stack exchange. Edited it

Answer (score 1):

Also, Sophos has a free antivirus for linux and also has tools for linux servers.

See here:

[www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx)

You may also want to check out security stackexchange:

[security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)