# Antivirus for general purpose user? Yay or nay?

Tags: antivirus

Hi I've just installed Ubuntu on to my mum's laptop for her after we had to restore to factory settings and couldn't get windows back. It's looking like we're going to keep Ubuntu on it and I was wondering whether or not to install antivirus on her laptop?
We already have a subscription to Panda but their software doesn't work on Linux OS's, so I was hoping to get something cheap if not free if we needed one at all.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: No. There's no need for one unless you're _really_ paranoid.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed

Comment: I agree with Rinzwind.  If you go down that link it talks about `clamav` that I use all the time and it's free.  It is not that I am afraid of getting a virus in my linux installation, but I don't want to pass one on to another system.