# Connecting an External Hard Disk Drive to Ubuntu OS. Is My Data at Risk?

Tags: hard-drive, antivirus

I have an External HDD that I use to connect to a Windows OS (protected by Antivirus & similar tools).

If I connect it to my Ubuntu machine (which is not protected by any Antivirus tools) would it be a threat to my 900Gbs of files stored on my External Drive, after years of hardwork?

Though I've done a bit of research regarding this, I've not yet got a clear answer.

Please reassure a newbie to Ubuntu it is safe.

Comment: Hey guys, I am in a state of emergency... Need help .. Please answer my question if you know the answer..  Thank you

Comment: See [Do i need to have antivirus installed](http://askubuntu.com/q/10373/295286)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viruses in the Linux world are, for all practical matters, non-existent. Unless you have valid reasons to believe that the Ubuntu machine you're going to use has been tampered with to destroy data in devices inserted in USB ports, you haven't nothing to worry about.

However, from your question it looks like (I might be wrong) you haven't any backup of the data files.  If this is the case, you should do that ASAP: files can be damaged not only by viruses but also by disk crashes or human errors, such as deleting the wrong directory.

Comment: hey dr01, by 900Gbs, I mean data in my HDD...

Comment: You question was very unclear then. I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks dr01, I understand what you saying but can you suggest me a way in which I can be sure that connecting my HDD to the Ubuntu OS would not damage or, corrupt the data in my HD (apart from the back up plan &all)..

Comment: Do you have *any* reason to suspect that the Ubuntu OS *will* damage the files in your HD...?

Comment: Being a newbie to it (Ubuntu )&not having any Antivirus stuff in it(may be a habit for having used Windows for years) are enough reasons for me to be suspicious... You think they're valid enough reasons?

Comment: &no.. The machine to which I'm going to connect does not have history of damaging Files or corrupting them as of now...

Comment: You're being too paranoid. Accessing files is the OS' work.

Comment: Thanks man.. Guess, we filtered it to quiet well an answer. Still do comment if you think of something that we missed... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Linux users have much less concern with such things as viruses because Windows saturates the marketplace. There is little concern of your external HDD would pick up a virus when connecting to a linux OS. Also, data loss is not a concern as the Linux OS will show what is there just as in Windows explorer, but files will only be changed if you do the changing. 
  I have a dual boot laptop (find myself using Ubuntu almost exclusively) and can see my Windows partitions at any time I wish from the Linux side within file manager. I have never had to be concerned with data loss in these partitions.
  If you are working with an external HDD, you would need to mount this drive before seeing, and each partition would have to be mounted (see man mount in a terminal).
  If this answer does not allay your concerns, my best advice is to not leave the external HDD on the system any longer than is necessary. Do what you wish to do with the external HDD and then umount and remove. Make the most of your copies (pics?) to minimize the time this external HDD is available.

Comment: I'm not concerned much about data loss from my HDD, than, I am from them being corrupted on connecting to an Ubuntu operated system that itself is not protected by any such protective tools as you rightly mentikned that we dont really have a significant risk regarding viruses in Ubuntu Ecosystem..

Comment: I get your point but tell me if there is anyway in which I can be sure that connecting my HDD to an Ubuntu OS (that is not in anyway protected by any antuvirus in contrast to my Windows machine) would not be a threat to my data from being corrpted or damaged?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are concerned to the point that no one or no information is going to allay your fears. 
Ubuntu does not need antivirus tools. Not necessary. Your Windows experience, which I understand being an extensive Windows user myself, has you convinced that accessing your Windows HDD from an Ubuntu system still would need antivirus protection. That being the case, your best bet is to not access this
external HDD from Ubuntu to avoid your concerns, best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular thought, malware in the Linux world does exist, but it's very very rare, and has to take advantages of elaborate vulnerabilities. In the Linux world, bigger threat is to servers, rather than desktop users: just as example, my server on Digital Ocean is being constantly attacked from variety IP addresses, but in all the time that I've had Ubuntu on my personal laptop - not a single threat.

Windows malware cannot take advantage of a Linux system, however, if you have `wine`, the Windows compatibility layer, there is a chance of Windows malware attempting at attacking your system.

The point is that you are 99.99% safe and sound on Ubuntu. If you do feel safer with antivirus , there are `clam-av`  , `tiger` , all of which are installable through `apt-get` or Software Center. In all the time I've used Ubuntu thus far, I haven't heard of anyone using them , at least on a personal machine, and for myself there was no need thus far.