# Need help with ESET NOD32 installation

Tags: software-installation, password, 15.10, antivirus

I'm new to Ubuntu, a complete rookie. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. And I'm trying to install ESET NOD32 anti-virus on Linux desktop, the 64-bit version of course. I just downloaded the file `eset_nod32av_64bit_pt_br.linux` (I'm Portuguese).

When I execute the file, the console pops up. I enter the password but the console says it's wrong and I know it's not wrong. The error I am getting is: `wrong password, command failed to execute, Aborted (core dumped)`. I even tried [this tutorial](http://support.eset.com/kb2653/?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: I would like to point out [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/63101/89737) from [security.se], and the feeling of me and many other Linuxistas is that antivirus is mostly superfluous, if you're not stupid. I'm not saying you *never* need it, and there are use cases, but for normal userland it's not really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need an anti-virus if it's your personal computer. GNU/ Linux has a different permissions model and there are way less threats for your *client* GNU/ Linux based computer.

The extension .linux sounds funny to me. I would look for something which ends with .deb!

In case you really want an anti-virus for Linux, I would go for Avast: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-and-update-avast-antivirus-in-ubuntu be sure to take the amd64 version if possible. Visit this official repository: http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/pool/ and take this file:  avast_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb which is currently the latest.

Else, look for Debian in dists, since Ubuntu is based on Debian an is compatible with it.

Comment: Of course, you should look up older similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed