# Is it necessary to use Antivirus software?

Tags: malware, antivirus

If I don't use any Anti-Virus is there any problem ? To keep my data safe what should I do ?

Comment: _Refer related Ubuntu Documentations_  : **[Do I need anti-virus software?](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-antivirus.html)** **and** **[Why do I need anti-virus software?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)**

Comment: "To keep my data safe what should I do ?" is an unrelated question to "anti-virus".

Comment: Rinzwind: If you have problem with my question then I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep your Ubuntu system up to date (software updates), you need no antivirus. I am running Linux since 1992 and never got any virus in near 25 years.

See: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Comment: If you do not keep your system up to date you do not need it either ;-)