# Is it true that Ubuntu is Virus Free?

Tags: 12.04

One of my friend said that **Ubuntu is Virus** **free** I don't know whether it is true or not plz answer guyz I am new to this Community....

Comment: There are fewer viruses, but no it can still get them.  The reason this is, is because most virus writers attack the machines that there are more of or that they have an issue with.  In this case that would be Windows.  Apple used to proclaim it was virus free, until somebody wrote a virus for it as well.  Virus writers want to do damage or spread their code, and Linux has a smaller deployed footprint than the other platforms.  As with any computer, don't open files you have received from unknown sources.

Answer (score 2):

**In Short:**

- No ... even the Linux world is not entirely virus free
- BUT - the amount of known malware for linux is pretty small compared to the Windows world
- Most well known viruses are often focusing the windows world & often limited to Windows based on the used technique.

**Want to know more?**

Please consider reading [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed) - as it really collect already a big amount of information regarding your question.
Wikipedia has an [article about linux malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware) as well - might be worth a read as well.
Additional information can be found in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus).

Answer (score 0):

[Anti-Virus Community Help Wiki Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)

This Link should give you a  better understanding.