# How can I install an .exe file (Avast Internet security) in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, windows, antivirus

I cannot find a way to install `Avast Internet Security 6.0.1367.exe` from the exe file directly.

I would like to know how to install it on my computer, to know the right commands to install it from terminal.

Comment: It depends on the software. What's the `exact` application you're trying to install? Not generic like "antivirus".

Comment: The program that I try to install is this: Avast Internet Security 6.0.1367.exe

Comment: It's very debatable including at this question at Ask Ubuntu: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Comment: Why do you wan't to install a Windows virus-scanner software on Ubuntu ? Why do you wan't to instal virus-scanner software on Ubuntu at all?

Answer (score 6):

> I cannot find a way to install Avast Internet Security 6.0.1367.exe from the exe file directly.

Install Windows.

---

You are using Ubuntu, not Windows so please have a look at this link for [Avast Linux](https://support.avast.com/en-eu/article/131/). You need to add their repository:

```
sudo echo "deb http://deb.avast.com/lin/repo debian release" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key add /path/to/avast.gpg
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you can install it...

```
sudo apt-get install avast
sudo apt-get install avast-fss
sudo apt-get install avast-proxy
```

You do need an account and a license:

> **How to insert a license file to Avast Security for Linux?**
>
> The access to the program repositories is not restricted in any way, you can always obtain all the latest packages, but for running the components, a license file is required. The license for the products comes in the form of a file named `license.avastlic`. After obtaining the license file, copy it into the `/etc/avast` directory:

```
sudo cp /path/to/license.avastlic /etc/avast
```

---

Mind though: being smart is far more important than to rely on 3rd party software. THEIR interest is making money of your paranoia. Nothing more. Use on-line mail (so downloads stay on-line and the mail provider will scan your mails for you) and do not download/install software from random sites (we use Software Center) and there is no need for this kind of software.

Comment: Thanks, @Rinzwind,  I'll try and tell you if it worked. Now I find it impossible

Comment: FWIW they make it hard for some reason. The avast.gpg is text in a pdf file, you need to copy it to make the file, but the format is wrong, so you need to add a blank line after the header. Then contact their sales department to get a license file ... wow. Why do they even bother offering it.

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to install and run many Windows applications in Ubuntu through the [WINE compatibility layer](/q/316025/175814), anti-virus software is not among them on principle because it's tied tightly to features<sup>1</sup> of Windows that WINE doesn't emulate and never will.

There are *native* anti-virus solutions as outlined in “[What antivirus programs are available?](/q/79722/94914)” but it's [debatable to what extent Linux systems benefit from them](/q/10373/94914).<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Meaning particular programming interfaces (sometimes even private ones) and implementation details, not practical functionality that other operating systems lack.

<sup>2</sup> taken from [karel’s comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035770/how-can-i-install-an-exe-file-avast-internet-security-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1685758_1035770)

Comment: Thanks, @David Foerster . I'll try and tell you if it worked. Now I find it impossible

Comment: Thanks @ David Foerster , for the advice. I already have experience in the Stackoverflow-Spanish site and I know how it works. If I have not done it yet, it is because I could not prove it, I have problems with the Ubuntu computer and it is repairing itself.
When I put the advice into practice, I'll let you know. Thank you.