# ClamAV: Unknown response from database.clamav.net

Tags: clamav

I have installed ClamAV 0.103 version.
When I run the freshclam manually I get the following response:

```
ClamAV update process started at Wed Mar 17 15:43:55 2021
daily.cld database is up to date (version: 26111, sigs: 39610058, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
main.cvd database is up to date (version: 59, sigs: 45649002, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode.cld database is up to date (version: 333, sigs: 902, f-level: 63, builder: awillia2)
```

But when it runs as a scheduled job, I get the following response. Just to give you a history - I initially had version 0.99 and uninstalled it and installed 0.103 version.

```
Mar 17 08:17:33 freshclam[1003]: Received signal: wake up
Mar 17 08:17:33 freshclam[1003]: ClamAV update process started at Wed Mar 17 08:17:33 2021
Mar 17 08:17:33 freshclam[1003]: getfile: Unknown response from database.clamav.net (IP: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)
Mar 17 08:17:33 freshclam[1003]: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Mar 17 08:17:33 freshclam[1003]: Trying again in 5 secs...
Mar 17 08:17:38 freshclam[1003]: ClamAV update process started at Wed Mar 17 08:17:38 2021
Mar 17 08:17:38 freshclam[1003]: getfile: Unknown response from database.clamav.net (IP: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)
Mar 17 08:17:38 freshclam[1003]: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Mar 17 08:17:38 freshclam[1003]: Trying again in 5 secs...
Mar 17 08:17:43 freshclam[1003]: ClamAV update process started at Wed Mar 17 08:17:43 2021
Mar 17 08:17:43 freshclam[1003]: getfile: Unknown response from database.clamav.net (IP: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)
Mar 17 08:17:43 freshclam[1003]: Can't download main.cvd from database.clamav.net
Mar 17 08:17:43 freshclam[1003]: Giving up on database.clamav.net...
Mar 17 08:17:43 freshclam[1003]: Update failed. Your network may be down or none of the mirrors listed in /etc/freshclam.conf is working. Check http://www.clamav.net/doc/mirrors-faq.html for possible reasons.
```

Can you please let me know what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While I don't know how to answer your question, unless you are cleaning infected files to be shared with an Windows user, you really don't need an antivirus. See this answer for details. https://askubuntu.com/a/10375/124466

Comment: You are trying to download from a server that does not exists. Pick another mirror.  And indeed: unless you want to scan windows files there all you do is lessen the life of your hardware. There is no need for a virus scanner. Rootkits would be better to scan for.

Comment: I intend to use this server as a service to scan all the files that are uploaded into web application. This was working until few days ago when I had version 0.99 . That version doesn't work anymore. So had to upgrade to 0.103 version. As I have already stated with 0.103 version if I manually run the freshclam it works but not when it's automated.

Comment: @Abhi, found any solution?