# suitable anti virus for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Since yesterday, I have been seeing notifications that"your data is under threat...rqstz.stoneheartseeker.top.you need to install anti-virus...when I click that it asks to purchase  Macfee antivirus.
Is there a freely available anti-virus for cleaning viruses in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Before you install anything: where have you been seeing those notifications? This sounds very much like adverts disguised as "warnings" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising) - see e.g. [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124429/virus-warning-after-clicking-on-a-google-search-results-link) and related ones on Information Security.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to have antivirus software installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Comment: Sounds much like Malvertising - don't fall for that. Do your own research..

Comment: Track down the issuer of the message. Use, e.g. `ps -ef`. It's lying to you. Unix/Linux has a completely different philosophy and design; Viruses don't work on Linux, no Anti-Virus is needed. Consider how a Windows virus misuses Windows capabilities and services to elevate privilege (the first step in any Evil Plan); none of these is available in the Linux environment.